# Save WWW::Mechanize::File to disk using FileUtils

Tags: ruby, mechanize

Using Mechanize with Ruby I get a certain file using `agent.get('http://example.com/foo.torrent')`, with FileUtils or otherwise, how do I save this file to my hard drive (for instance, in a directory wherefrom the script is running)?

P.S. `class => WWW::Mechanize::File`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `WWW::Mechanize::File` has a `save_as` instance method, so I suppose something like this might work:

```
agent.get('http://example.com/foo.torrent').save_as 'a_file_name'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the `Mechanize::File` class is not the most appropriate for large files. In those cases, one should use the `Mechanize::Download` class instead, as it downloads the content in small chunks to disk. The file will be downloaded to where the script is running (although you can specify a different path as well). You need to set the default parser first, create a new one or modify an existing parser. Then, save it to the desired path:

```
agent.pluggable_parser.default = Mechanize::Download
agent.get( "http://example.com/foo.torrent}").save("path/to/a_file_name")
```

Check [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mechanize/Mechanize/PluggableParser) and [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mechanize/Mechanize/Download) for more details. Also, there's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360043/using-wwwmechanize-to-download-a-file-to-disk-without-loading-it-all-in-memory/9105153#9105153) in Stackoverflow.