# Using WWW:Mechanize to download a file to disk without loading it all in memory first

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I'm using Mechanize to facilitate the downloading of some files. At the moment my script uses the following line to actually download the files...

```
agent.get('http://example.com/foo').save_as 'a_file_name'
```

However this downloads the complete file into memory before dumping it to disk. How do you bypass this behavior, and simply download straight to disk? If I need to use something other than WWW:Mechanize then how would I go about using WWW:Mechanize's cookies with it?

Comment: Please note that the `Mechanize::File` class is not appropriate for large files. In those cases, one should use the `Mechanize::Download` class instead, as it downloads the content in small chunks to disk. Check [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mechanize/Mechanize/PluggableParser) and [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mechanize/Mechanize/Download) for more details.

Answer (score 38):

What you really want is the Mechanize::Download

http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/Download.html

you can use this way:

```
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
agent.pluggable_parser.default = Mechanize::Download
agent.get('http://example.com/foo').save('a_file_name')
```

Comment: I would add that I've just exactly used your solution except I had Mechanize:FileSaver instead of Mechanize:Download. And that hasn't worked => Files are save to disk but without any contents..0 kb. I've just replaced it with Download and the whole is perfect :) Thanks

Comment: Where does the file get saved?

Comment: @carbonr with `agent.get(url).save(File.join(dir, filename))` the file will be saved into the dir you specify.

Comment: You could save file to ~/Downloads folder use this code `agent.get(download_url).save(File.join(Dir.home, 'Downloads', file_name))`

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [Mechanize::FileSaver](http://docs.seattlerb.org/mechanize/Mechanize/FileSaver.html)? It looks like it can do what you require.

Here is an example that saves all the PDF files it encounters:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
agent.pluggable_parser.pdf = Mechanize::FileSaver
agent.get('http://example.com/foo.pdf')
```