# Confusion with mechanize installation

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I want to install Mechanize, but it looks like there are two gems. Should I need to install both "mechanize-downloader" and "mechanize", or only "mechanize"?

```
gem install mechanize-downloader 
gem install mechanize
```

Or:

```
gem install mechanize
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Mechanize](http://rubygems.org/gems/mechanize) is the main gem, and is used to automate interactions with websites (including downloading files).

[mechanize-downloader](http://rubygems.org/gems/mechanize-downloader) is a gem for downloading files with a progress bar. It extends Mechanize to provide a progress bar as the files are being downloaded.

Running `gem install mechanize-downloader` installs Mechanize as well since it is a dependency. Mechanize is a standard, and it's easy to get help should you run into problems.

Take a look at "[Using WWW:Mechanize to download a file to disk without loading it all in memory first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9105153/429758)" for an example of how to download files using Mechanize.

For a more general introduction to working with Mechanize, check out "[#191 Mechanize](http://railscasts.com/episodes/191-mechanize).

"[Mechanize examples](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/EXAMPLES_rdoc.html)"" is another useful resource.

Comment: Mechanize-downloader requires Mechanize, and doesn't run separately. Instead, it extends Mechanize allowing a progress bar as files are retrieved. It doesn't run by itself.