# Can I use Mechanize to download files with .docx and .xlsx,.txt extensions?

Tags: ruby, mechanize, mechanize-ruby

I browsed the documentation [Mechanize](http://rubydoc.info/gems/mechanize/Mechanize/PluggableParser). The below is for `.pdf` only.

```
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
agent.pluggable_parser.pdf = Mechanize::FileSaver
agent.get 'http://example.com/foo.pdf'
```

1. *But can I also download .docx,.xlsx,.txt file also?*
2. *when the file download will be done,what would be it's default directory? Can we change the save file directory too?*
3. *which browser would it select during downloading? Can we also change the browser control?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The type of file doesn't matter; any file accessible over the net can be obtained via mechanize, which is a tool for automating interaction with Mechanize.
2. The file will be stored in the directory where the program was run. Use [Mechanize::Download](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/Download.html) instead of `Mechanize::FileSaver` to specify where the file should be downloaded to. Example code here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9105153/429758 (Specify the full path in the filename)
3. Mechanize doesn't use a browser while downloading. `For all intents and purposes, Mechanize acts like a web browser with no user interface` via http://ruby.about.com/od/tasks/a/The-Mechanize-2-0-Handbook.htm

Do checkout the [EXAMPLES page on mechanize documentation](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/EXAMPLES_rdoc.html) for further examples about how to use mechanize.

Comment: Any Good suggestion would you like to me give regarding - How to use the docs? I am talking about this as, I am first time seeing such kind of docs. Basically I am from Oracle domain. The basic trouble I am suffering with the doc is that,not all the procedures has a tiny code to explain the syntax. So how to do such homework, to understand what proceudre can be used how inside a code. The doc has such tiny codes with small amount of procedures, not for all. Any suggetions on that. I am really eager to know this platform,but the documentation sometime helps,sometime not.

Comment: For any subject in Ruby/Rails, the first thing I do is to check if there is a `RailsCasts` episode on that. Here is the one for mechanize: http://railscasts.com/episodes/191-mechanize That gives a good intro; after that it will be easier to understand the official documentation.

Comment: Okay! this question is not subjective still would like to ask you that - Are you from `India`? :) I am from Kolkata,India.

Comment: I am done Sir. Really the nice flavour i am not getting due to that the immaturity fact of mine, with the documentation. With each of the procedure they have provided the source code,but not a tiny syntactical example. That's the pain for the new learner- basically who are doing self study!

Answer (score 2):

It might be more straightforward to just save your file like so:

```
File.open('myfname.pdf', 'wb'){|f| f << agent.get('http://example.com/foo.pdf').body}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will check the same.