# Parse array of links and downloading them using Ruby

Tags: ruby, mechanize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I download a binary file over HTTP using Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263540/how-do-i-download-a-binary-file-over-http-using-ruby)

I have an array called `pdf_links` containing links to PDF files collected by the Mechanize gem.

```
http://site/file1.pdf
http://site/file2.pdf
http://site/file3.pdf
http://site/file4.pdf
http://site/file5.pdf
http://site/file6.pdf
http://site/file7.pdf
```

I need to save all the PDF files to my directory.

What is the best way to do it with Ruby?

I tried to do it using *nix string but I'm receiving an error:

```
pdf_links.each do |d|
    system %x{ wget #{d} }
end
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a save method in mechanize to store it

[Save WWW::Mechanize::File to disk using FileUtils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898257/save-wwwmechanizefile-to-disk-using-fileutils)

http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/File.html#method-i-save

or you can use ruby lib 'open-uri'

```
 require 'open-uri'
 pdf_links.each do |link|
  File.open(file_path_to_store, 'wb') {|f| f.write(open(link).read)}
 end
```

Answer (score 2):

Mechanize can do it:

```
agent.get(d).save
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, found a mistake in array first url was wrong due to mistake on the site.